# CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found c DigiCert сертификатом

Tags: android, ssl, https, devops, tls

**Дано:**

1. Android девайсы разных вендоров, все в Индии. Версии ОС - все (от 5 до 14 Android). Всего больше сотни разных девайсов, вот первый десяток моделей:

   ```
   M2010J19SI
   CPH2579
   MT2111
   SM-M315F
   220733SI
   CPH2139
   CPH1933
   EB2101
   RMX3780
   ```
2. Сервер с платным сертификатом для TLS - `DigiCert Global Root G2` (https://www.digicert.com/kb/digicert-root-certificates.htm)
3. Приложение, отправляющее сетевые запросы с девайсов из п1 на сервер из п2, используя либу `OkHttp`

**Проблема:**

Указанные девайсы, судя по информации, которую программно собираем - не могут до сервера достучаться из-за SSL ошибки.

В системе сбора статистики наблюдаем ошибки такого вида:

```
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.


Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.


Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

**Предположение:**

На девайсах отсутствует нужный сертификат в списке доверенных сертификатов системы.

**Подтверждение предположения:**

1. Берём любой девайс/эмулятор
2. Отключаем в его настройках сертификат из п2 Дано (на эмуляторе отключать тут: `Settings->Security->Encryption&Credentials->Trusted credentials`) - см скриншот.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4. Пробуем отправить сетевой запрос - получаем ошибку аналогичную наблюдаемой в системе сбора ошибок.
5. Вручную вшиваем отключенный сертификат в приложение вот так:
6. добавляем файл сертификата (`digi_cert_global_cag2`) в res/raw
7. создаём в res/xml файл network_security_config с содержимым:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted=“false">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="@raw/digi_cert_global_cag2" />
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

- прописываем конфиг в манифесте:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    …
    <application
      android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    …
```

5. Сетевые запросы теперь успешно отправляются.

**Проблема:**

1. Ручное вшивание в приложение сертификата не решило проблему - девайсы указанные продолжают генерировать `SSL` ошибку, о чём сообщает нам наша система сборка ошибок.
2. Девайса на котором проблема воспроизводится без ручного отключения сертификата в наличии нет

**Неподходящие решения:**

Использовать обычный `LetsEnctypt` сертификат - не вариант, ибо требуется платный сертификат по требованию третьих сторон.

**Вопросы:**

1. Кто-то с таким сталкивался?
2. Что делать?

<s>Игнорировать эту ошибку (случается у крайне незначительного кол-ва юзеров) тоже не вариант - DevOps-ы резко против</s>

Comment: 2. Мне кажется вы сами знаете: купить device который воспроизводит данную ошибку.

Comment: не может ли быть проблема в провайдере? если трафик проксируется через что-то сомнительное, то SSLHandshakeException в порядке вещей. что, если настроить okhttp с `X509TrustManager` чтобы подтверждать любые сертификаты?